# About android Sqlite safety in multi-process case

Tags: android, sqlite

In my application, there exist more than one process, and in each process, I need access the same SQLite database (of course, it means more than 2 theads), so I worried about not only the thread-safety about the SQLite, but also the process-safety.

One solution for this case is [using content-provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248319/database-handling-with-2-processes). But from android sdk, [it warns that its methods may be called from multiple threads and therefore must be thread-safe](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/10/sqlite-contentprovider-thread-safety.html). If content provider itself not necessarily means thread-safe, how can I assume it is process-safe?

The [article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/10/sqlite-contentprovider-thread-safety.html) also clarifies that SQLiteDatabase itself is synchronized by default, thus guaranteeing that no two threads will ever touch it at the same time. What if in the multi-process case? Can two processes modify the same table at the same time? Will it crash?

Comment: no, they can't. you will get SQLiteDatabaseLockedException

Comment: @mianlaoshu you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: @orium What would be the solution for the database-locked issue for multiple processes? Is enableMultiInstanceInvalidation enough for this use case?

Comment: so...... i went down this path, using Room DB, and multiple processes by using enableMultiInstanceInvalidation to build the Room DB instance. It worked, but in my telemetry, i could see lots of users getting SQLiteDatabaseLockedException exceptions. the situation was improved by adding retries with exponential backoff, but it was still an issue to 200/12K users. next, I am going to try having only 1 service in a separate process mutate the DB while the rest only do read operations.....wish me luck :(

Answer (score 4):

You can find answer here: https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html (point 5). Briefly:

> Multiple processes can have the same database open at the same time. Multiple 
>   processes can be doing a SELECT at the same time. But only one process can be 
>   making changes to the database at any moment in time, however.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple processes behave just like multiple threads, i.e., their transactions are safe from being interfered with by each other.

Comment: But with the two processes, I actually could get 2 SQLiteDatabase instances, will it cause any potential problems about the thread- or process-safety?

Comment: Different processes have different address spaces; the two objects cannot even see each other. (They only see the lock on the DB file.)

Comment: Yes, i know that. So it means, the SQLite database lock should be global to the entire system, if one app acquires the lock, any other application in another process should get a "locked" state if accessing the DB, right?

Comment: Yes; a transaction writing to the DB file is global to any system that accesses the file.

Comment: I just ran a simple test on a 2.3 device. Without content provider it crashes (database is lock exception) otherwise it works well. But on a 6.0 device both work. Not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: @Wayne Newer platforms are implemented to wait when it sees a lock. But it won't wait longer than 2.5 seconds. If database is still locked after 2.5 seconds, the 'database is locked' exception is thrown.

Comment: @hqzxzwb I am facing database is locked exception (code 5) in the multiprocess application. what should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Android `Room`, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62334005