# android room database locked

Tags: android, database, android-room, locked

I had been getting " android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException" exception from production when I had been using 3rd party non-thread safe sqlite libraries. I checked all the threads and connection closing, I made all instances singleton but I wasn't able to solve the problem (I haven't even reproduce case myself). Then I moved my orm to Room database which is completely thread safe. But I'm still getting the exactly same error from production. So isn't Room db thread safe and isn't it take care of concerns for conventional sqlite libraries as Google mentioned? Is there anybody who faces db locked error with Room?

Comment: This question is impossible to ask if you don't post the code. If you get the same errore you should think about if the error is real and if it's real you probably have a problem with your implementation.

Comment: FYI facing the same issue.

Comment: Did you get any solution for that?

Comment: This problem disappeared for me from Crashlytics ever since updating Room to a newer version. I think it was a library issue

Answer (score 0):

Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/63849367/3256989 .
In short words, try to use `enableMultiInstanceInvalidation()` during building RoomDatabase.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting Journal Mode to `JournalMode.AUTOMATIC`. Worked fine for me.

Sample code from my project

```
INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        MyDatabase.class, "myDatabase")
                        .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2)
                        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                        .setJournalMode(JournalMode.AUTOMATIC)
                        .build();
```

[Android Room Database Journal Mode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.JournalMode)

Comment: As per official doc : JournalMode.AUTOMATIC is the default value when no explicit value is specified.The actual value will be TRUNCATE when the device runs API Level lower than 16 or it is a low-RAM device. Otherwise, WRITE_AHEAD_LOGGING will be used.